# Как правильней организовать такой блок условий?

Tags: c#, оптимизация, if

```
        bool myBool = false;
        if (!myBool)
        {
            if (someCondition1())
            {
                myBool = true;
            }
        }
        if (!myBool)
        {
            if (someCondition2())
            {
                myBool = true;
            }
        }
        if (!myBool)
        {
            if (someCondition3())
            {
                myBool = true;
            }
        }
```

У меня есть такой блок условий. Методы someCondition() выполняются достаточно медленно, поэтому выгодней вызывать их только если myBool = false. Как можно такой код привести к более "правильной/красивой" форме? Можно конечно использовать goto, но хотелось бы без него.

Comment: `if (!myBool) { if (someCondition1() || someCondition2() || someCondition3()) {  myBool = true;  }  }`

Comment: Точно. Тогда лучше myBool = someCondition1() || someCondition2() || someCondition3(); Извините за столь тупой вопрос)